# My select input calculator is not working, how can I figure out why?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a calculator that pics values from 4 select dropdowns real time, and goes on to update three divs below based on whatever the selected values are.

However I keep getting NaN for two of the answer divs.

My console.log is clean so I cannot get where this is coming from.

```js
document.querySelector("select").onchange = function() {
  recalculate()
};

function recalculate() {
  var locations = document.getElementById('locations').value;
  var average_price = document.getElementById('average_price').value;
  var donation_rate = document.getElementById('donation_rate').value;
  var customers_number = document.getElementById('customers_number').value;
  var sales_result = document.getElementById('sales_result').innerHTML;
  var customers_result = document.getElementById('customers_result').innerHTML;
  var donations_result = document.getElementById('donations_result').innerHTML;
  var weeksInYear = 52;
  //customers_result = locations * weeksInYear * customers_number;
  //donations_result = donation_rate * customers_number* locations * average_price;
  //sales_result = locations * customers_result * average_price;
  document.getElementById('customers_result').innerHTML = locations * weeksInYear * customers_number;
  document.getElementById('donations_result').innerHTML = donation_rate * customers_number * locations * average_price;
  document.getElementById('sales_result').innerHTML = locations * customers_result * average_price;
};
```

```css
.ng-scope {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  line-height: 1.42867;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#restaurant-landing .section-margins {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.row {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#restaurant-landing {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.calculator-fields {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 39px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
  background-color: #2a4563;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.field-wrapper {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.calc-label {
  float: left;
  width: 58.33333%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.calc-field {
  float: left;
  width: 41.66667%;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.result-box {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  background-color: #54822b;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.result-number {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 62px;
  color: white;
}

.result-label {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28.6px;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="ng-scope">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="calculator-fields">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="locations"><span class="hidden-xs"># of </span>locations:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="locations" id="locations">
                  <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                  <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                  <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                  <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
                  <option label="5" value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
                  <option label="6" value="6">6</option>
                  <option label="7" value="7">7</option>
                  <option label="8" value="8">8</option>
                  <option label="9" value="9">9</option>
                  <option label="10" value="10">10</option>
                  <option label="15" value="15">15</option>
                  <option label="20" value="20">20</option>
                  <option label="25" value="25">25</option>
                  <option label="40" value="40">40</option>
                  <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
                  <option label="100" value="100">100</option>
                  <option label="200" value="200">200</option>
                  <option label="300" value="300">300</option>
                  <option label="400" value="400">400</option>
                  <option label="500" value="500">500</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="average_price">avg. <span class="hidden-xs">ticket </span>price:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="average_price" id="average_price">
                  <option label="$4" value="4">$4</option>
                  <option label="$5" value="5">$5</option>
                  <option label="$6" value="6">$6</option>
                  <option label="$7" value="7">$7</option>
                  <option label="$8" value="string:$8">$8</option>
                  <option label="$9" value="string:$9">$9</option>
                  <option label="$10" value="string:$10">$10</option>
                  <option label="$11" value="string:$11">$11</option>
                  <option label="$12" value="string:$12" selected="selected">$12</option>
                  <option label="$13" value="string:$13">$13</option>
                  <option label="$14" value="string:$14">$14</option>
                  <option label="$15" value="string:$15">$15</option>
                  <option label="$16" value="string:$16">$16</option>
                  <option label="$17" value="string:$17">$17</option>
                  <option label="$18" value="string:$18">$18</option>
                  <option label="$19" value="string:$19">$19</option>
                  <option label="$20" value="string:$20">$20</option>
                  <option label="$25" value="string:$25">$25</option>
                  <option label="$30" value="string:$30">$30</option>
                  <option label="$35" value="string:$35">$35</option>
                  <option label="$40" value="string:$40">$40</option>
                  <option label="$45" value="string:$45">$45</option>
                  <option label="$50" value="string:$50">$50</option>
                  <option label="$75" value="string:$75">$75</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="donation_rate">donation:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="donation_rate" id="donation_rate">
                  <option label="15%" value="0.15">15%</option>
                  <option label="20%" value="0.20">20%</option>
                  <option label="25%" value="0.25">25%</option>
                  <option label="33%" value="0.33">33%</option>
                  <option label="40%" value="0.40">40%</option>
                  <option label="45%" value="0.45">45%</option>
                  <option label="50%" value="0.50">50%</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="customers-number"># Customers:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="customers_number" id="customers_number">
                  <option label="10" value="10">10</option>
                  <option label="20" value="20">20</option>
                  <option label="30" value="30">30</option>
                  <option label="35" value="35">35</option>
                  <option label="40" value="40">40</option>
                  <option label="45" value="45">45</option>
                  <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="calculator-results">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-box">
              <div id="sales_result" class="result-number ng-binding">$11,440</div>
              <div class="result-label">sales</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-box result-left-mobile">
              <div id="customers_result" class="result-number ng-binding">2,860</div>
              <div class="result-label">customers</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-box result-right-mobile">
              <div id="donations_result" class="result-number ng-binding">$1,716</div>
              <div class="result-label">donations</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you are passing a string in the value in several of your options: `string:$8` and so on.

Comment: all the value you get from dom are string, just convert to number

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot that I do not like about this but this fixes the NaN issue

```js
document.querySelector("select").onchange = function() {
  recalculate()
};

function recalculate() {
  var locations = parseFloat(document.getElementById('locations').value);
  var average_price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('average_price').value);
  var donation_rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('donation_rate').value);
  var customers_number = parseFloat(document.getElementById('customers_number').value);
  var sales_result = document.getElementById('sales_result');
  var customers_result = document.getElementById('customers_result');
  var donations_result = document.getElementById('donations_result');
  var weeksInYear = 52;

  customers_result.innerHTML = locations * weeksInYear * customers_number;
  donations_result.innerHTML = donation_rate * customers_number * locations * average_price;
  sales_result.innerHTML = locations * customers_result * average_price;
};
```

```css
.ng-scope {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  line-height: 1.42867;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#restaurant-landing .section-margins {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.row {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#restaurant-landing {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.calculator-fields {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 39px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
  background-color: #2a4563;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.field-wrapper {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.calc-label {
  float: left;
  width: 58.33333%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.calc-field {
  float: left;
  width: 41.66667%;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.result-box {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  background-color: #54822b;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.result-number {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 62px;
  color: white;
}

.result-label {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28.6px;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="ng-scope">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="calculator-fields">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="locations"><span class="hidden-xs"># of </span>locations:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="locations" id="locations">
                  <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                  <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                  <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                  <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
                  <option label="5" value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
                  <option label="6" value="6">6</option>
                  <option label="7" value="7">7</option>
                  <option label="8" value="8">8</option>
                  <option label="9" value="9">9</option>
                  <option label="10" value="10">10</option>
                  <option label="15" value="15">15</option>
                  <option label="20" value="20">20</option>
                  <option label="25" value="25">25</option>
                  <option label="40" value="40">40</option>
                  <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
                  <option label="100" value="100">100</option>
                  <option label="200" value="200">200</option>
                  <option label="300" value="300">300</option>
                  <option label="400" value="400">400</option>
                  <option label="500" value="500">500</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="average_price">avg. <span class="hidden-xs">ticket </span>price:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="average_price" id="average_price">
                  <option label="$4" value="4">$4</option>
                  <option label="$5" value="5">$5</option>
                  <option label="$6" value="6">$6</option>
                  <option label="$7" value="7">$7</option>
                  <option label="$8" value="8">$8</option>
                  <option label="$9" value="9">$9</option>
                  <option label="$10" value="10">$10</option>
                  <option label="$11" value="11">$11</option>
                  <option label="$12" value="12" selected="selected">$12</option>
                  <option label="$13" value="13">$13</option>
                  <option label="$14" value="14">$14</option>
                  <option label="$15" value="15">$15</option>
                  <option label="$16" value="16">$16</option>
                  <option label="$17" value="17">$17</option>
                  <option label="$18" value="18">$18</option>
                  <option label="$19" value="19">$19</option>
                  <option label="$20" value="20">$20</option>
                  <option label="$25" value="25">$25</option>
                  <option label="$30" value="30">$30</option>
                  <option label="$35" value="35">$35</option>
                  <option label="$40" value="40">$40</option>
                  <option label="$45" value="45">$45</option>
                  <option label="$50" value="50">$50</option>
                  <option label="$75" value="75">$75</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="donation_rate">donation:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="donation_rate" id="donation_rate">
                  <option label="15%" value="0.15">15%</option>
                  <option label="20%" value="0.20">20%</option>
                  <option label="25%" value="0.25">25%</option>
                  <option label="33%" value="0.33">33%</option>
                  <option label="40%" value="0.40">40%</option>
                  <option label="45%" value="0.45">45%</option>
                  <option label="50%" value="0.50">50%</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="field-wrapper">
              <div class="calc-label">
                <label for="customers-number"># Customers:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="calc-field">
                <select name="customers_number" id="customers_number">
                  <option label="10" value="10">10</option>
                  <option label="20" value="20">20</option>
                  <option label="30" value="30">30</option>
                  <option label="35" value="35">35</option>
                  <option label="40" value="40">40</option>
                  <option label="45" value="45">45</option>
                  <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="calculator-results">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-box">
              <div id="sales_result" class="result-number ng-binding">$11,440</div>
              <div class="result-label">sales</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-box result-left-mobile">
              <div id="customers_result" class="result-number ng-binding">2,860</div>
              <div class="result-label">customers</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-box result-right-mobile">
              <div id="donations_result" class="result-number ng-binding">$1,716</div>
              <div class="result-label">donations</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```